# Where to download PayPal MEC library?

Tags: paypal

Where can I download PayPal Mobile Express Checkout library for iOS.
All the links redirect to new PayPal iOS SDK.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've voted to close this question - any answers will be links that will inevitably break in the course of time. As a result, I don't think the question is a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answers the question: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions